# Highcharts wrong size on window maximize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, highcharts

Odd problem here. I am constructing a highchart and placing it within a bootstrap 3 carousel. When the window is in any size but 'maximized', the chart labels and data all fit the area correctly. However when maximizing the window, both axis labels and titles are moved out of the visible space. The odd thing is that this happens even if the difference in window size from non-maximized to maximized is a few pixels.

Does anyone know of a fullscreen setting for highcharts or something similar that could be causing this? My avid googling has come up with nothing.

The chart construction code is rather long, but I will copy what is necessary here. Also note, that the setSize() animations and functionality is all perfect when the window is not maximized.

```
// The relevant highcharts code
var chartOptions = {
                chartType: 'column',
                reportContainer: 'reportResultsContainer',
                chartContainerName: 'reportChart',
                title: 'Driver Tonnages (Total ' + totalTonsSum.formatMoney(2, false) + ')',
                //floatingTitle: true,
                //titleY: 20,
                chartName: 'Drivers',
                yaxisName: 'Tons',
                //rotateDegrees: -90,
                chartData: deliveryData,
                xAxisTitlePadding: '0px',
            };
// later on
$('#' + chartContainerName).highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: chartType,
            //margin: [50.50,50,50]
        },
        title: titleObject,
        subtitle: subtitleObject,
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: headerFormatHtml,
            pointFormat: pointFormatHtml
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: cursor,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    y: rotateDegrees != 0 ? -20 : 0, // 15 pixels up from the top
                    rotation: rotateDegrees,
                    formatter: dataLabelformat,
                },
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            title: {
                text: xaxisName,
                useHTML: true,
                style: { paddingTop: xAxisTitlePadding }
            },
            labels: {
                step: xAxisLabelStep,
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: yaxisName,
            },
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: xaxisName,
            type: chartType,
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: chartData,
        }, ]
    });
// the set size function, called on window resize
$('.highchart').each(function() {
    $(this).highcharts().setSize($('#carouselContent').width() - 35, $('#carouselContent').height() - 35, doAnimation=true)
});
```

Here are the images of the charts. The first is when the window is minimized 2px under the maximized resolution. The second is the chart when maximized. Notice that the chart size as a whole is the same.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgZlt.jpg

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: I would love to, but as I said the methods creating the charts are rather complex as the program as a whole is C# MVC with CSHTML tied in. Even if I took the hour it would take to make a jfiddle, I doubt that I could reproduce the effect since most of the code creating/running my version would need to be stripped out. I'm confident that the answer is not a botched line of code, but rather a plugin conflict or DOM setting I missed with highcharts. This is more of a theory/knowledge question than anything.

Comment: Can you check if the setSize is called if window is maximized? And is it called with proper values? There is also a [Chart.reflow()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow) that is usually helpful when chart's container is being resized.

Comment: setSize is called on $(window).resize(), so yes it is called when the window is maximized. This is the only time setSize is ever called in the code. A resize() event is triggered on chart render so that it is given the appropriate size on page load. I checked the numbers via console for when the function is called and everything is in order.

Upon inspection with firebug, it would appear that the xaxis size is overflowing the chart area (which is correctly set) for some reason... IT does not appear to be included with the rest of the formatting of the chart.

Comment: After testing reflow(), it would appear that it gives the chart the correct width, but not the correct height... I will test it a bit more, but I don't think that function is the answer.

Comment: It is hard to guess what could be wrong without recreating of the chart. Maybe setSize is called before a chart is being fully rendered? Could you test it with setTimeout?

Comment: The 'on render' issue would only cause a problem for the first resize call. All the others thereafter would work, so that isn't it. I tested it with timeout as you requested, to no success.

Comment: When `$('#carouselContent').height() - 35` is set as a chart's height, then that value is height of the chart? If yes, then jQuery is returning wrong value(?) or if not, then chart's size is different that set through setSize, because of something that is forcing the chart to change its size. There seems to be a need for debugging.

Comment: To be sure it is the only thing affecting the size, I commented out my re-sizing function, and the chart did not re-size after render. The thing to note here is, as I said in the original post, when you change the window size by two pixels, but go from a windowed to maximized mode, there are drastic changes in the chart size. With the function I am using, there should be a linear change in re-size to match the linear change in window size. I think there is some oddity within the highcharts plugin itself when used within a bootstrap carousel, rather than a coding error. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a long time looking at this, and finally have a solution.

In my example above, I was using the charts within a bootstrap 3 carousel. When a panel is not shown, the div holding it gets its CSS 'display' set to 'none'. Highcharts freaks out when this is the case, and doesn't format itself correctly. As a solution, I bound a handler to watch the slide event which is fired prior to the transition (slide.bs.carousel for Bootstrap), which fires a JQuery `$(window).resize()` event. This triggers the chart to format itself correctly, as it is after the CSS 'display' property has been reverted from 'none' to 'normal', but before the transition animation shows the chart itself.

Point of Order: some other plugins seem to dislike it when you fire a window resize() in this method (DataTable confirmed so far), and distort their content. If this happens to you, please be sure to use an 'if' clause to mask the function fire depending on the content that is about to be shown.

Sample Code:

```
Carousel.$Wrapper.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) { onSlide(evt) });
```